# Twitter api GET Call {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying do GET call for twitter  through SFDC here is the apex class code ..

```
String consumKey       =EncodingUtil.urlEncode(apiData.Oauth_Consumer_Key__c,'UTF-8');
      String othNonce =Encodingutil.urlEncode(oathNonce, 'UTF-8');
      signature =Encodingutil.urlEncode(signature, 'UTF-8');
      String othToken =Encodingutil.urlEncode(apiData.Oauth_Token__c, 'UTF-8');

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

            req.setEndpoint('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=tesr_s&count=10');

            req.setMethod('GET');



            string reqstring = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'+consumKey+'",'+
                               'oauth_token="'+othToken+'",'+
                               'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",'+
                               'oauth_timestamp="'+timestamp+'",'+
                               'oauth_nonce="'+othNonce+'",'+
                               'oauth_version="1.0",'+

                req.setHeader('Authorization',reqstring);
                req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


                Http http = new Http();
                HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
                system.debug('req  () ===>>>>>'+req);
                system.debug('res.getBody() ===>>>>>'+res.getBody());
                return res.getBody();
```

Getting below error .
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}.

> System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Test&count=10,
>   Method=GET] 23:26:47.0 (901503445)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:586
>   23:26:47.0
>   (901599227)|CALLOUT_RESPONSE|[102]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Authorization
>   Required, StatusCode=401] 23:26:47.0
>   (901616748)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[102]|Bytes:90

Comment: You need to be create remote sites for twitter api

Comment: Your auth credentials are incorrect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to be added Remote Sites to get access to twitter api.

To add a remote site setting:

- From Setup, enter Remote Site Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Remote Site Settings.
- Click New Remote Site.
- Enter a descriptive term for the Remote Site Name.
- Enter the URL for the remote site.(https://api.twitter.com/1.1/)
- Optionally, enter a description of the site.
- Click Save.

**Apex Code :**

```
 public class Scontroller
        public String sBody{get;set;}
        public String tweets{get;set;}
        public String access_token {get;set;}
        public Scontroller()
        {   
            String keyencoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('CYXp886M6g04xwouOHLYg4UJf','UTF-8');
            String secretkeyencoded = EncodingUtil.urlEncode('5qC4A3JZDF8you0VtKx95AJqROlXi2oihTkJgVNNsv8pVQ2cjT', 'UTF-8');
            String sFinal = keyencoded + ':' + secretkeyencoded;
            Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(sFinal);
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
            req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
            req.setBody('grant_type=client_credentials');
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

            JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
            while(parser.nextToken() != null)
            {
                if(parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME)
                {
                    String fieldName = parser.getText();
                    parser.nextToken();
                    if(fieldName == 'access_token')
                    {
                        access_token = parser.getText();
                    }

                }
            }


        }

        public String gettweetsss(){

            HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();

                req2.setEndpoint('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterdev&count=12');
                req2.setMethod('GET');

                //Call Bearer token Method
                String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
                req2.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

                Http http = new Http();
                HTTPResponse res = http.send(req2);

                tweets = res.getBody();
                return tweets;  
        }
```

May be this community answers could you more insight on this,
https://twittercommunity.com/t/errors-message-could-not-authenticate-you-code-32/1223/35

Comment: That error is not for a missing remote site. It's a credentials issue

Comment: Its added then also same issue.

Comment: @Javed.S.M You Checked now